# Separate integer fractions from variables?

Tags: output-formatting, expression-manipulation

Whenever I write a rational number times a variable, i.e.:

```
(2/3)a
```

the result Mathematica displays looks very cringeworthy:

> $$\frac{2a}{3}$$

I would prefer the output to look like

> $$\frac{2}{3}a$$

Even a substitution rule like

```
/.(x_Integer q_)/y_Integer -> (x/y) q
```

does not correct the issue. Is it possible to make the output look proper?

Comment: You have a strange idea of what's proper. I'd take the first form any time...

Comment: @V.E. for me it depends; with long-ish polynomials, I do like having the fractional coefficient and the monomial being separated by a thin space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is what `$PrePrint` is for, since you only want to affect how the expression looks, and I'm guessing you want it to happen automatically for every input. Using `$PrePrint` thus allows you to use `Out[n]` without worrying about the held expressions.

This seems to work (but I would like to find a better way to take care of the signs between terms in a sum):

```
$PrePrint = # /. r_Rational x_Symbol :> Sign[r] HoldForm[Evaluate[Abs[r]]] HoldForm[x] &
```

You can add more replacement rules if you like of course, to treat e.g. polynomials:

```
$PrePrint = # /. {r_Rational x_Symbol :>
                   Sign[r] HoldForm[Evaluate[Abs[r]]] HoldForm[x],
                  r_Rational x_Symbol^i_Integer :>
                   Sign[r] HoldForm[Evaluate[Abs[r]]] HoldForm[x^i]
                 } &
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do this by using a custom [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule:

```
MakeBoxes[Times[a__, r_Rational], StandardForm] := MakeBoxes[Times[Defer[r], a]]
```

Some examples:

```
Graphics[Circle[]]/2+Graphics[Rectangle[]]/3
Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]
Expand[(x-y)^4/24]
```

[image]

One nice thing about this approach is that the output is copy/pastable.

The other answer doesn't work right for any of these inputs, and the outputs generated are not copy/pastable.

Comment: what about the case where one uses .m file and run through command line. There it does not work. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186607/output-formatting?noredirect=1#comment527043_186607